# prompt user to update data on logon using bootstrap modal and php

Tags: php, bootstrap-modal

I want to prompt user to update his profile on logon, if he has not updated some of his data using bootstrap modal. I check for null values for the given user in database and then if the values are null the user must be prompted to update the data

Comment: where is your  code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as I understood, you want to let the user update data if there are null values inside the database. You can do it like this, you let the user log in, direct him to the page where you intend to send them after logon. Keep in mind that you need to know inside PHP that does the user have the null values inside database (you can add that data to a session for example). After that, you just check it, if there are null values, show him the modal.

```
<?php
if ($_SESSION['update_user'] !== FALSE) {
    ?>
    <!-- modal html code -->
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Can you explain the use of if ($_SESSION['update_user'] !== FALSE)

Comment: Sorry, when the user is being logged on (data checked from SQL), you can use the $_SESSION variable (if the session is started) to keep a value which you need. My idea was to check if there are null values inside SQL, if there are, set $_SESSION['update_user'] to TRUE or 1, so when you get to the page where you want to show the modal, you can just check the value of update_user and show the modal if it is 1/TRUE or not if it's 0 / FALSE.